# Перекодировка из urlencode

Tags: url, php

Как мне перекодировать %D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8 в слово "Игорь"?

Предыстория: я установил виджет для входа на сайт с помощью акка ВКонтакте. А тот передает мне в GET имя, UID, фамилию, и ссылку на картинку.
Например:

```
http://codeigniter.prodimport.pro/index.php/catalog?&uid=38039883&first_name=%C8%E3%EE%F0%FC&last_name=%CC%E0%E9%EE%F0%EE%E2&photo=http://cs304710.userapi.com/u38039883/a_1590df03.jpg&photo_rec=http://cs304710.userapi.com/u38039883/e_1b645ba4.jpg&hash=274e437d80873dc4fb6f2773b3d48e35

<?php
$hash = $_GET['hash'];
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$first_name = $_GET['first_name'];
$last_name = $_GET['last_name'];
$photo = $_GET['photo'];

?> 
<p>Ваш UID:<?php echo $uid;  ?></p>
<p>Ваше имя:<?php echo urldecode($first_name);  ?></p>
<p>Ваша фамилия:<?php echo urldecode($last_name);  ?></p><br>
<img src='<?php echo $photo;?>'>`
```

Что он выдает:

```
Ваш UID:38039883  
Ваше имя:   
Ваша фамилия:
```

**`URLDECODE()` не помогает, или я не понимаю, как с ним работать... объясните, пожалуйста!**

Comment: Как ты работаешь с urldecode?

Comment: Что он выдаёт-то?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: `$_GET` уже содержит в себе декодированные строки. Повторно применять `urldecode()` не нужно. Что выводит просто `echo $_GET['first_name']`?
И, для красоты, `print_r($_GET)` приведите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @srgiks, оно выводит пустую строчку...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужна функция [rawurldecode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rawurldecode.php)!

Пример:

```
echo rawurldecode('%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C');
```

Результат: игорь

Comment: @ARISTARH, вся проблема,наверное, в том,что оно вообще выводит пустое поле вместо %D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C

Comment: тебе вообще нужно описать поставленную задачу, чтоб выбрать нужный способ решения! Например у ВК есть API, и можно с лёгкостью получить в JSON строке ответ, или при помощи CURL можно спарсить что-то, вообщем вариантов много!

Comment: @ARISTARH, Я использую API!!! Мне надо получить Данные пользователя и вывести их на страницу.

Comment: пример: http://codeigniter.prodimport.pro/index.php/catalog?&uid=38039883&first_name=%C8%E3%EE%F0%FC&last_name=%CC%E0%E9%EE%F0%EE%E2&photo=http://cs304710.userapi.com/u38039883/a_1590df03.jpg&photo_rec=http://cs304710.userapi.com/u38039883/e_1b645ba4.jpg&hash=274e437d80873dc4fb6f2773b3d48e35

Comment: отдельно создай вопрос как это сделать

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте установить кодировку страницы в UTF-8. Думаю, что проблема может быть в этом.
 Если изменение кодировки страницы ни к чему не приведет, то попробуйте следующий вариант:

```
echo iconv('cp1251','utf-8',$_GET['first_name']);
```

P.S. Между rawurldecode() и urldecode() - разницы почти нет, за исключением того, что в urldecode "плюс" декодируется в символ пробела.